# Batch join PDF files, layout for cutting

Tags: layout

I have 20,000 PDF files which is a mail merge of post card files. (Front has unique QR code, back has address.)

Our printer requires artwork on 11x17 with cut marks. So my task is to layout each set of 6 cards onto a sheet.

So far I have created the template file, here is that:

[image]

I have tried ImageMagick for this task but this is producing raster images. I think that tool is not suited for this task.

Is Ghostscript capable to perform this merge?

Comment: Yes, (if you know how to write postscript) although you probably want to use something like scribus or inDesign. But then had you known how to write postscript you would have generated the QR codes with that instead! (because its easier than embedding a font or working with a bunch of separate files)

Answer (score 2):

If you know a little bit of LaTex, you shoul try the package **pdfpages** which provides the macro **\includepdf**.

It's very powerfull to make composite document from existing PDF document (or part of PDF documents).

LaTex can produce PDF output.